Is there a function or way to stop the setinterval function from keep on running after a match in jQuery or JS?
The project that I'm working on, generates  2 different p elements and each one is triggered independently. It takes about 5 seconds to load after the callback. I have no control over any of these  p elements, but to wait for it to finish loading so I can run a script. I'm using the setInterval() function to check when one of the p elements loads up. I then insert a div element before the p element. For this I'm targeting the class of each p element with a switch statement.
The issue I have is that this will keep generating the div over and over and I only need it once after each call. I can stop the intervals with the clearInterval() but that kills it completely and have no way to restart it because it will not fire back again even if I call the setInterval() function.
Is there a way I can approach this maybe in a different and better way without the setInterval()?
var parent = $('.result-content'); //This is where the generated element will be placed.
var isAvailable = $(".result-content .available");// The code will run when this shows up
var isNotAvailable = $(".result-content .not-available");// The code will run when this shows up
var availableWrapper = $('<div>',{ class: 'availableWrapper', text:'This box gets generated.' });// This doesn't exist until its called
var notAvailableWrapper = $('<div>',{ class: 'notAvailableWrapper', text:'This box gets generated.' });// This doesn't exist until its called



function whichOneisVisible() {
    var target = $('.result-content').children("p:first");

        switch (target.attr('class')) { 
          case "available": 
             console.log('Congrats, this p element is available!');
                isAvailable.after($(availableWrapper));
            clearInterval(check);
            break;
          case "not-available": 
             console.log('Sorry, this p element is NOT available!');
             isNotAvailable.after($(notAvailableWrapper));
            break;
          default:      
            console.log('Nothing is available!');
        } 
}
check = setInterval(whichOneisVisible, 550);    

The html..
<div class="result-content">
    <p class="not-available">This P element is not available</p>
    <div>This is just a div</div>
    <div>This is just a div</div>
    <div>This is just a div</div>
</div>


Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

this sounds like XY problem. You should wait for the loading to end instead of keep checking over and over.

can  you stop the setInterval()  without preventing the next code from running and then freely restart the setInterval()? If not, then this is the issue I ran into.

this will keep generating the div over and over - what will? there's no div being generated in your code at all - the bug may be in code you haven't shown

@Jaromanda X
I have updated the code.

You can either declare a function like toggleCheckOnInterval for start/stop the intervals. Or, right, a separate functions for that.
function whichOneisVisible() {
    // ...
}

let check;
function toggleCheckOnInterval() {
    if (!check) {
        check = setInterval(whichOneisVisible, 550);
        return;
    }
    clearInterval(check);
    check = null;
}
toggleCheckOnInterval(); 


it performs the same behavior, which is the same issue I have. It keeps generating the element on the fly... any other suggestions?

You have mentioned the issue is "but that kills it completely and have no way to restart it because it will not fire back again even if I call the setInterval() function." ,
If you need alternate solution, give me a minimal reproduction of your issue  here.

I have updated the code. Please check it out.
